# After adding a library to android studio through build.gradle, I can't import the library into my kotlin file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I added a dependency to my build.gradle in android studio but when I open my project and go to a specific  kotlin file to import the library, it doesn't want to import and then I can't access it, what can I do about it.

I checked the implementation for any typo error but none, I went to the main menu, opened the build tab and then cleaned the project and rebuilt it but to no avail, I also went to the file tab in the main menu and then clicked on the invalidate caches to remove any conflicting dependencies but nothing changed but then when I then ran my android emulator, these errors came which are:

> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. and also, Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.github.tehras:charts:0.2.4-alpha.,

which the latter is the dependency I added to make a bar chart in jetpack compose.
I also checked for updates but I was using the current updates in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Check out setting.gradle, i guess you don’t have jitpack.io, which is required for “com.github.xxx” dependencies